# C# - which event to populate a combobox before it's visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, populate

I'm currently updating it on click, but this results in the user being able to see the repopulation occur. Which other event can I use which will allow me to handle it myself, then show the combobox when i'm ready? ( after population)

Comment: WP7? WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're developing, but that combobox is probably on a window or so that will have an event that fires on show. Use that event to populate the combobox in.

[edit]  Ah Winforms. Use the Load event.

[edit2] On each click eh.

Alright. I found a dirty solutions that advises you to override the WndProc and capture messages, but I think it's better to inherit the combobox and override OnDropDown to perform you populating before calling the ancestor's OnDropDown method.

You should populate the box when entered too, because a value may be selected using the keyboard (arrows) without even dropping down the box. You'll need both if you want it on each selection, because a click only causes the Enter event when the box didn't have focus before.

Comment: I want to repopulate it on each click, not just on form load.

Comment: @amx If you want to populate in on each click, bind to click event and load event. What's the problem ?

Comment: gor, the problem is described in the first line of the question. thanks Golez for the subclassing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [ComboBox.DropDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call SuspendLayout() before updating and calling ResumeLayout() after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

combobox.add_HandleCreated triggers after the control is created as the form is loading